# AWS KMS subscription fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kms

I enter the console, go to IAM management, Encryption Keys: it says: "You are not currently subscribed to the AWS Key Management Service. Click here to subscribe." I click, and it returns me to console's home.

I have all Security Status approve, and I have S3 permission, is there something else to do? or does someone knows how to fix this?

Comment: If this is a new account, it may take a few hours for all services to become accessible.  If not, you should contact AWS support.

Comment: Well it has been 6 days since it was created, I contact support but I'm still waiting for it to be fix

Comment: Did you get a response from support?  What did they say?  Curiously, there don't seem to be any [support forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=182) posts where users describe having this same issue.

Comment: Yeah, they fix it, they said it was a problem with the account.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on the resubscribe link here https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/error-access-service/
2. Log out & log back in

That worked for me. This seems to happen to AWS accounts that are several years old (as of 2018). More info here: https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/7a5nwv/unable_to_subscribe_to_aws_key_management_service/